# Is there any "Ubuntu touch" vmdk/iso for trying on VirtualBox?

Tags: virtualbox, ubuntu-touch, virtualization, ubuntu-emulator, genymotion

I have **[Genymotion](https://www.genymotion.com/)** and **VirtualBox** installed on my Ubuntu 15.10 with which I can explore almost-all the mobile **android** Operating Systems.

I am very much exited to try out **Ubuntu touch** in the same way before I buy an Ubuntu phone.

So, Is there any official links to download "Ubuntu touch" vmdk/iso for trying on VirtualBox (or on any other Virtualization software) ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The 'Canonical' way to run Ubuntu Touch in emulation is to use the `ubuntu-emulator` rather than VirtualBox and friends. If you are using Trusty Tahr or later run the following:

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-emulator ubuntu-emulator-runtime ubuntu-emulator-images
```

Then you create the emulation:

```
sudo ubuntu-emulator create just_testing
```

There will be a reasonable download and then you can run your copy of Ubuntu Touch in emulation:

```
ubuntu-emulator run --scale 0.75 just_testing
```

The `--scale 0.75` option can be varied to produce the 'phone' size of your choice or even omitted completely if desired. Another option to manipulate is `--memory 720` which specifies in megabytes the amount of memory available to the emulator.

A screenshot of all of this running on my own system:

[image]

**References:**

- Ubuntu Docs: [Touch Emulator](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Touch/Emulator)
- [Emulate Ubuntu Touch](http://www.linuxuser.co.uk/tutorials/emulate-ubuntu-touch)
- [A quickstart guide to the Ubuntu emulator](http://davidplanella.org/ubuntu-emulator-quickstart-guide/)

Comment: WOW! Its awesome... Thanks @andrew.46 . But some minor problems. It would be really help full if you could help me solve those.
1. No ***Back*** and ***home*** buttons, I couldn’t find any buttons to Go back

2. Bad resolutions. I cant read some of the text inside it... can I make it bigger?? see [this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/nIoYz.png)

Comment: One more : Its asking me **Passphrase**... I did not set any passphrase, I set only a pin on my first use.... but now its asking me passphrase :(

Comment: Hmmm... passphraseI believe is 0000 (4 x zero). To make everything bigger omit the `--scale 0.5`, For Back and Home I am not sure, I am struggling to get it working under VM and I have just realised that VirtualBox does not support nested virtualization! Great to hear that you have at least a roughly working copy though :)

Comment: Works much better under vmware player, I shall add a screenshot to my answer when all is fully loaded

Comment: I ahve VMWare Workstation Installed :-) please tell me how to install inside it

Comment: Performance is agonizingly slow under emulation, I suspect that you would be better avoiding emulating from within a VM. Can be done but it is slow...

Comment: OIC the confusion: I meant that vmware player runs better than virtualbox, not that a VM runs better than a bare install...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/37179/discussion-between-severus-tux-and-andrew-46).

Comment: The Ubuntu phones don't have back and home buttons, they don't have any hardware buttons at all actually. Everything is done using gestures from different sides of the phone. Not sure how that'll work with a mouse in the emulator though.

Comment: @andrew.46 Can I get Internet on this emulated phone??

Comment: Not on my system I'm afraid :(