# What is the default username and password for ubuntu touch?

Tags: ubuntu-touch, ubuntu-emulator

I decided to try Ubuntu touch on my computer for the first time ever today following [This Post's answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/743438/is-there-any-ubuntu-touch-vmdk-iso-for-trying-on-virtualbox) as instructions. After running `ubuntu-emulator run --scale 0.75 just_testing` in around 3 minutes, the terminal showed `ubuntu-phablet login:`. I did not set any type of password or user so it must be something default right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The username is `phablet`, you don't need to enter a pin if you did not set it. You can change that in the settings or when creating a new emulator.

Comment: I didn't get a pin though

Comment: Actually, after entering phablet I didn't need to enter a password. THanks